# Distinguish two queries within a union

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

How would I distinguish where a record is coming from in the following example union query:

```
SELECT id, name, datetime FROM events
UNION
SELECT id, name, datetime FROM festival
ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

The way I'm using it in PHP is:

```
$stmt = $cxn->prepare('SELECT id, name, datetime FROM events WHERE id = ? UNION SELECT id, name, datetime FROM festival WHERE id = ? ORDER BY datetime DESC');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $event_id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $name, $datetime);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "ID: " . $id . "\n";
    echo "Name: " . $name . "\n";
    echo "Date: " . $datetime;
}

$stmt->close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id, name, datetime, 'events' FROM events
UNION
SELECT id, name, datetime, 'festival' FROM festival
ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

**PHP**

```
$stmt = $cxn->prepare('SELECT id, name, datetime, "events" as tablename FROM events WHERE id = ? UNION SELECT id, name, datetime, "festival" as tablename FROM festival WHERE id = ? ORDER BY datetime DESC');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $event_id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $name, $datetime, $table);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "ID: " . $id . "\n";
    echo "Name: " . $name . "\n";
    echo "Date: " . $datetime;
    echo "Which Table: " . $table;
}

$stmt->close();
```

Comment: How would I get that column in the way I have it set up in PHP since I'm binding results?

Comment: An improvement would be to use `UNION ALL` since these records cannot match anymore

Answer (score 0):

you could do this by adding one more column and differentiate it like:

```
SELECT id, name, datetime, 'E' as fromwhere FROM events
UNION
SELECT id, name, datetime,'F' as fromwhere FROM festival
ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

the `fromwhere` column will tell you if its from events or festival.

Comment: How would I get the `fromwhere` column in the way I have it set up in PHP since I'm binding results?

Comment: is it not possible to add the fromwhere in the query itself in php ?? like this SELECT id, name, datetime, 'E'FROM events WHERE id = ? UNION SELECT id, name, datetime , 'F' FROM festival WHERE id = ? ORDER BY datetime DESC'